# A waiting dialog with "wx.MessageDialog"

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I use ...

```
waitingdlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'Waiting for soundcard signal...', 'Test', wx.CANCEL)
waitingdlg.ShowModal()

while inputvolume < 10:       # inputvolume is a global variable
                              # modified by another thread linked to soundcard input
    wx.MilliSleep(10)

waitingdlg.Destroy()
```

... in order to wait for an external signal (for example : the input level of a soundcard is higher to a certain decibel level).

I would like the `wx.MessageDialog` to automatically close when the trigger happens (when `inputvolume` becomes `>= 10`).

But because of the `waitingdlg.ShowModal()`, the `while` never happens !
On the other hand, without the `ShowModal`, the dialog is not displayed.

**How to make this wx.MessageDialog wait for an external trigger to close itself?**

Answer (score 3):

You can create another thread to check the volum.
And please use wx.Dialog instead since wx.MessageDialog is not a real wx.Dialog and it doesn't respond to Destroy().

```
    import wx
    import threading

    def timer_start(dlg):
        t = threading.Timer(0,test_func,(dlg,))
        t.start()

    def test_func(dlg):

        global inputvolume
        print "inputvolume: ", inputvolume

        if inputvolume < 100:
            wx.MilliSleep(10)
            timer_start(dlg)
            inputvolume += 1
        else:
            #dlg.EndModal(wx.CANCEL)
            dlg.Destroy()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        inputvolume = 0
        app = wx.App(False)
        fame = wx.Frame(None)
        fame.Show()

        waitingdlg = wx.Dialog(fame,title = 'Test')
        timer_start(waitingdlg)
        waitingdlg.ShowModal()

        app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Such a shame that `wx.MessageDialog` doesn't respond to `Destroy()` (by the way, why is it so ?). It's a shame to have to redesign a whole messagebox myself (with textboxes, buttons, `Bind()`, etc.) since `wx.MessageBox` was ready to use !

Comment: Use the GenericMessageBox if you don't want to redesign everything

Comment: @Basj please check this [link](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Destroy-a-wx-MessageDialog-after-a-given-amount-of-time-td2852005.html). It is said that "The wx.MessageDialog is not a real wx.Dialog, it's just a convenience
wrapper around a native API function.  As such it does not implement
most of the wx.Dialog API".